# How to slice two dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I know there are so many questions for this, but my case it is different. I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to slice an array in PHP the result comes with `mysqli_fetch_array()`  The result comes in this way from the back-end:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ([0] => 1 [dt_id] => 1 [1] => 09:00 AM [dt_time] => 09:00 AM) 
    [1] => Array ([0] => 2 [dt_id] => 2 [1] => 09:15 AM [dt_time] => 09:15 AM) 
    [2] => Array ([0] => 3 [dt_id] => 3 [1] => 09:30 AM [dt_time] => 09:30 AM)
) 

for ($row = 0; $row < $recordscoun; $row++)
{
    for ($col = 0; $col < count($records[$row]); $col++)
    {
        if('09:15 AM' == $records[$row][$col]) {
            print_r(array_slice ($records, $row));
        }
    }
}
```

It's not slicing the array, I searched a lot but found no solutions.

Comment: you have a multi-dimensional array - not a 2d one

Comment: You might find this easier using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, and referring to the columns by name instead of looping over them

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs okay sorry about that as already mentioned i'm new to php

Comment: @iainn any suggestion?

Comment: What's the desired result? An array of all rows that have `dt_time` greater than `09:15 AM`? I'd recommend to solve this in SQL if the other rows aren't needed.

Comment: @KiranSingh no need for sorries :) just letting ya know aha :)

Comment: @simon yes if the time is 09:15 or greater than that I need all previous time to be removed from the array

Comment: As I said, solve it in your SQL query. Select only the rows with the desired time by using a `where` clause.

Comment: @iainn mysqli_fetch_assoc worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off doing this in the query, however for PHP `array_slice` is not what you want here.  Filter the array comparing the times:

```
$records = array_filter($records, function($v) {
                                      return strtotime($v['dt_time']) >= strtotime('9:15 AM'); 
                                  });
```

Comment: returns the same array

Comment: yes, it working.and liked the way you solved in just one line :)